# Artifactory REST API Latest Release Version

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to develop a script to query Artifactory for artifact details. The AQL api does the trick for providing me SHA1, SIZE and location. However I need to restrict this information to a specific release. Does Artifactory provide an API endpoint that will return the latest release version for a specific repo? I've already looked over the [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout) API and while this will work I would need to provide a specific artifact to key off of.

Basically I'm trying to gather a complete list of artifact details from a given repo based on latest release. I'm after the sha1, size, and name of a given artifact for a specific release.

Comment: What do you mean by latest release for a specific repo? versions are usually per artifact/package. Do you want to find all the latest versions of all the artifacts in a specific repo?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need, all the latest artifacts for a specific repo. I don't need to download the artifacts I just need the SHA, size and location.  That's why I'm using AQL to return that information.

Comment: Do you have a way to find the version number with this query?

`items.find(
  {
    "repo":
      {
        "$match":"my-repo"
      }
  }
)`